# MFC: Proper way to override HashKey() of CMap<> objects?

Tags: collections, mfc

I was trying to override `HashKey()` function for MFC CMap class.  Page 290 of *Programming Windows with MFC Second Edition* gives an example of just a function like: `UINT AFXAPI HashKey(CString & string)` and says to just use specific type. Well, that just resulted in errors, looking things up, it appears now to use `template<>`.   How do we override those?  Example:

```
typedef uint32_t myint_t;
CMap<myint_t, myint_t&, uint32_t, uint32_t&> m_MyCMap;
```

I want to override for `myint_t` but says it already exists in `afxtempl.h`

If I had to override for all `int` types, how could I even do that?  This is the only CMap I'm using (that I know of, unless internally MFC is using some as well, which I would think is very possible).

So how do you properly override the `HashKey()` for `CMap<>` of a given type?

TIA!!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for [HashKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/collection-class-helpers#hashkey) has all the information. It's a function template, and you need to provide a specialization that matches your `ARG_KEY` template type argument (`myint_t&` in your case):

```cpp
template <> UINT AFXAPI HashKey(myint_t& key)
{
   // ...
}
```

Standard C++ rules apply. In particular, you can only ever provide at most one specialization for any given type. A `typedef` in C++ declares a type *alias*; it doesn't introduce a new type and you cannot provide specializations for types that alias each other.

This extensibility point for `CMap` in MFC is provided for custom types. If you are using integral types or base MFC types as your keys, you need to accept the hash function provided by MFC. This is essentially the same behavior you get with standard containers like `std::map`.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried just myint_t key, so now trying with myint_t& key, but still doesn't like it.  It says:  error C2766: explicit specialization; 'UINT HashKey<ARG_KEY>(ARG_KEY)' has already been defined  with [ARG_KEY=UINT & ]

Comment: This is expected. You aren't introducing a user-defined type, but rather an alias of an integral type.